# How to control the size of diagbox(with long text) in psmatrix diagrams?

Tags: pstricks, psmatrix

The problem for me is the 4th and 5th line from the bottom

(code from an example of Herbert and the problem is where I try to add things ;-) )

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}


%\input{pssettings.tex}
\begin{document}
\psset{framearc=0.2,shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90}‎
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.75,colsep=1.5]% defines the distance between two frames
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,blur,shadow](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    & [name=SA] Solución Actual\\
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.65,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    & [name=SS] Generar Vecindad\\
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](1,1){0.20}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.20}{Current}
    \psline[linewidth=0.2]{->}(1,1)(0.5,0.5)
    & Elegir Mejor Vecino\\
    \psdiabox[shadow=true]{¿Is in the house of Mary?}
    &\psdiabox[shadow=true]{¿Is in the house of King?}& \\
    }}&
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this code give what you want? I put the contents of the dianodes in a `\parbox`. In addition the text in the last column is left aligned, while centred with respect to the King's \dianode.

```
     \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}
    \usepackage[pdf, x11names]{pstricks}%
    \usepackage{pst-node}
    \usepackage{pst-blur}
    \usepackage[margin = 1.5cm, nomarginpar]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newlength{\mylen}
    \settowidth{\mylen}{Elegir Mejor Vecino}

    \newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
    \newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
    \newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
    \newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\begin{document}
\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70!, shadowangle = -90}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.75,colsep=1.5]% defines the distance between two frames
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    & [name=SA] \parbox{\mylen}{Solución Actual} \\
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    & [name=SS] \parbox{\mylen}{Generar Vecindad} \\
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodepink(1,1){0.20}{Current}
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.20}{Current}
    \psline[linewidth=0.2]{->}(1,1)(0.5,0.5)
    & Elegir Mejor Vecino\\
    [mnode = dia, linearc = 0.05, shadow = true] \parbox{3cm}{\centering ¿Is in the house\\ of Mary?}
    & [mnode = dia, shadow = true] \parbox{3cm}{\centering ¿Is in the house of King?}& \\
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `shortstack{...\\...}`. I also changed your circle nodes into default circles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}

\newpsobject{BDisk}{pscircle}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{PDisk}{pscircle}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}

%\input{pssettings.tex}
\begin{document}
\psset{framearc=0.2,shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90}‎
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.75,colsep=1.5]% defines the distance between two frames
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,blur,shadow](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \BDisk[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}
    & [name=SA] Solución Actual\\
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \BDisk(0,0){0.15}
    \PDisk(-0.75,0.75){0.15}
    \PDisk(0,0.65){0.15}
    \PDisk(0.75,0.75){0.15}
    \PDisk(-0.75,0.15){0.15}
    \PDisk(0.65,0.15){0.15}
    \PDisk(-0.75,0.75){0.15}
    & [name=SS] Generar Vecindad\\
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \PDisk(1,1){0.20}
    \BDisk(0,0){0.20}
    \psline[linewidth=0.2]{->}(1,1)(0.5,0.5)
    & Elegir Mejor Vecino\\
    \psdiabox[shadow=true]{\shortstack{¿Is in the house\\ of Mary?}}
    &\psdiabox[shadow=true]{\shortstack{¿Is in the house\\ of King?}}& \\
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Is there any better and more elegant approach for [this kind of problem (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172376/19356)?

Comment: @IamwhoIsayIam Yes, use `\psLNode`, [see my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172473/33933).