# How to define a point between two points for a given length ratio?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, calculations

I have the points `A(0,0)` and `B(3, 4)`, I want a point that is `4/6` of the length of `AB` and lies on the the same line. How to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using TikZ and its `calc` library you can use the `( $ (<name1>)!<value>!(<name1>) $ )` syntax to find a point along the segment passing through `(<name1>)` and `(<name2>)`. In the example below, `( $ (a)!0.66666!(b) $ )` means a point that is two thirds away from `(a)` in the segment joining `(a)` and `(b)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,gray!40] (0,0) grid (3,4);
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,4);
\node[label={left:$A$}] at (a)  {};
\node[label={left:$B$}] at (b) {};
\draw (a) -- (b);
\node[label={left:$C$}] at ( $ (a)!0.66666!(b) $ ) (c) {};
\foreach \Nombre in {a,b,c}
  \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (\Nombre) {};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Andrew Swann** mentions in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172273/how-to-define-a-point-between-two-points/172274?noredirect=1#comment397971_172274), one can also let PGF do the decimal calculation and use

```
( $ (a)!4/6!(b) $ )
```

instead of

```
( $ (a)!0.66666!(b) $ )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, I'v had such a hard time reading the documentation, thanks again!

Comment: +1 Note that you can also let `tikz` do the calcualtion of the decimal: `($ (a)!4/6!(b) $)`

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, I've added a remark about this to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

With `tkz-euclide` you can use a barycentric coordinate, which can be used to place points between other points. A point **p** lying on the line between the points **A** and **B** can be written as (a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>)**p** = a<sub>1</sub>**A** + a<sub>2</sub>**B**, and (a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>) will be the barycentric coordinate of **p**.

A point that is 2/3 along the way between **A** and **B** can be found by the vector sum **A** + (2/3)(**B** - **A**) = (1/3)**A** + (2/3)**B**. From this you see that the barycentric coordinate of that point is (1,2), which is why

```
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=2)
```

is used in the below code. If you wanted the point placed 7/10 of the way between the two points, you'd use `\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=3,B=7)`.

This can only be used to place points *between* the two defined points, while with the TikZ solution in Gonzalo's answer, you can say for example `\node[label={left:$C$}] at ( $ (a)!2!(b) $ ) (c) {};` to place `c` the distance 2ab away from `a`, on the line through `b`, or even `\node[label={left:$C$}] at ( $ (a)!-1!(b) $ ) (c) {};` to place it ab away from `a` in the direction opposite of `b`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=4]
\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,4){B}

\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=2)
\tkzGetPoint{C}

\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Without using `calc` or any extra library, you can also place a node directly on a path, using the `pos=<pos>` option (where `<pos>` is the relative position on the segment, here 2/3).

MWE (based on Gonzalo Medina's code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[help lines,gray!40] (0,0) grid (3,4);
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (3,4);
  \node[label={left:$A$}] at (a) {};
  \node[label={left:$B$}] at (b) {};

  \draw (a) -- (b) node[label={left:$C$},pos=2/3] (c) {};

  \foreach \Nombre in {a,b,c}
  \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] at (\Nombre) {};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The isolated line is the one that matters. Note that this can be used even if you don't want a visible line between A and B, or if you want a line with specific parameters. Simply replace `\draw` with `\path`, with or without additional parameters.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,4);
\coordinate (C) at ({atan(4/3)}:4*5/6);
\draw (A)--(B);
\filldraw (A) circle (2pt) node[right] {$A$};
\filldraw (B) circle (2pt)node[right] {$B$};
\filldraw[red] (C) circle (2pt)node[right] {$\frac{4\times5}{6}=3.3333$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided). `standalone` class is a really good alternative as seen in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

A clean, lucky solution.

### Option - ∞ + 1

Using an exact factor `2 3 div` instead of `0.6666` in Christoph's answer.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45}]{A}(3,4){B}
    \psLNode(A)(B){2 3 div}{t}
    \pstGeonode(t){C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Option -1

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45,0}]{A}(3,4){B}([Xnodesep=2]{B}A){C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And dirty solutions with PSTricks.

### Option 0

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45,0}]{A}(3,4){B}([Ynodesep=1.3333]{A}B){C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Option 1

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45,0}]{A}(3,4){B}([nodesep=3.3333]{B}A){C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45}]{A}(3,4){B}
    \nodexn{(A)+.6666(B)-.6666(A)}{t}
    \pstGeonode(t){C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Option 3

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45}]{A}(3,4){B}
    \pnodes{t}(2,0)(2,4)
    \pstInterLL{A}{B}{t0}{t1}{C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To expand the existing PSTricks solution: There is a macro `\psLNode` in the `pst-node` package, which does exactly this:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,4)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,45}]{A}(3,4){B}
    \psLNode(A)(B){0.6666}{C}
    \psdot(C)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: `\psLNode(A)(B){2 3 div}{C}` might be preferred.